# Ant Design - Make Menu Uncollapsable/Unfoldable

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design with React. Ant Design has a menu component: https://ant.design/components/menu/

Is it possible to make the menu uncollapsable/unfoldable? I read the documentation, and there was no parameter to turn off folding/collapsing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I currently have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 37):

I know I'm coming late to the party but for other people struggling with this - there is an undocumented (as far as I could tell from official docs) prop of Menu component called `disabledOverflow`. Setting it to `true` solved it for me.

Kudos to VS Code editor, it suggested this property to me and saved my day!

Comment: You are a hero @MrTanguero!

unfortunately this props ins't present on official documentation

Comment: Worked for me. Been searching for days for the solution to collapsing menu.

Comment: Well sir, you saved so many others' day, so kudos to you!

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by including a min-width style object to the Menu

```
<Menu
    theme="dark"
    mode="horizontal"
    style={{minWidth: '800px'}}
>
...
</Menu>
```

Answer (score -3):

[Antd Inline Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-inline) This gives you a menu that does not collapse.

Moreover it is only collapsible when you give the

`inlineCollapsed={this.state.collapsed}`

props to Menu Component

Comment: Inline menu is collapsible. I have tried : `<Menu
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
              defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
              mode="inline"
            >` and the menu is definitely collapsible.

Comment: Yeah, this really is not true and even if it was it would be bad to be forced to use an inline menu.